Location Allocation - ArcGIS Pro - The next best location
I have recently performed a location allocation analysis in ArcGIS Pro. The result gave me one single best location, but I also want to know which location is the second and third best location.
Is there any way to do that? (if the first location turns out to be irrelevant).

If you're in your location-allocation layer, at the top of your screen you should see a "Facilities" drop down with the value of "1". You just need to change this to 3 to get the second and third locations that are best and then click "Run".

